# C#- Convert List (text) in to string Array (words)

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
l.Add("This is TEXT");
l.Add("Convert it to words");
```

How can I convert in string Array?

Like this:

```
string[] array = new string{"this","is","TEXT","Convert","it","to","words"};
```

Comment: @Aria: `l.ToArray()` will not perform internal split

Comment: @Aria :`.ToArray()`[As you mentioned in the comment], will gives you the output as `{"This is TEXT", "Convert it to words"}` not like this: `{"this","is","TEXT","Convert","it","to","words"};`

Comment: Yes right I thought he just want to convert it to array, I haven't understood it in the first go !!!!!

Comment: Maybe the tile should be along "How to get all seperate words as array from a List of strings that contain multiple words each"

Comment: OK, changing title from: Convert List (text) in to string Array (words)
to your suggested title.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to change title.

Comment: There is no option, actually.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<string> listArray = new List<string>();
listArray.Add("This is TEXT");
listArray.Add("Convert it to words");

// Convert

string[] arrayString = String.Join(" ", listArray).Split(' ');
```

Working [Example here..](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yOyu76)

Comment: DontNetFiddle - nice; Know about python fiddle and mysql but thats new to me. +1

Comment: @un-lucky please edit your answer , this is lock me unless your post be edited, I wanna undo down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Or use Linq with [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) (that operates on an IEnumeration, applies the same thing on each and puts all the result into one IEnumeration as result - see f.e. here: [Difference Between Select and SelectMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany))

```
List<string> listArray = new List<string>();
listArray.Add("This is TEXT");
listArray.Add("Convert it to words");

// this is the array holding all words
var result = listArray.SelectMany(el => el.Split(" ".ToCharArray())).ToArray();

// this puts , between any words in result to output it ...
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
Console.ReadLine();
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z9MtcQ)

Edit: Difference to un-lucky`s solution:

- He takes each sentence, concatenates them using a space producing an even bigger string. This resulting string then gets split on spaces to form your array.
- mine uses Linq to split each sentence into theire words and after it, all words are put into one IEnumerable collection, which I enumerate into an array.

Both produce the desired output. The SelectMany is probably "cheaper" because no long string has to be constructed first. One would have to take a look into the implementations though - for your problem the internal differences between both methods are moot to discuss.

Comment: `... el.Split(' ') ...`

Comment: I don't want comma in between.

Comment: @Nab: the commas only appear in the output as you cant see the array as such (only by placing a breakpoint after `var result = ...;` and inspecting result), Your "words" are in `result` wich is an `string[]` without the commas 

I added them only for outputting on console in `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko fair point, +1 on comment. Wont edit though. Yours is "cheaper" is my guess - unless the compiler sees that my `" "` is a const and optimizes it.

Comment: OK, I will check difference later.
Thanks!

Comment: @un-lucky My explanation of `Difference in answers` fair? Edit post if not.