# LINQ merging multiple lists

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm working on this puzzle https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/skynet-revolution-episode-2

In this puzzle i have to block an agent from reaching nodes in a network, by each turn selecting a connection that I want to cut. I can only cut connections directly connected to a gateway.

I have a list of gateways `List<Node>` gateways.
I already have initialized each node with a `List<Node>` Connections that contains the direct neighbors

Since gateways can be connected to more than one node, I am interested in the nodes that are exactly 1 node away from the gateways, so I can identify which one of those nodes (lets call them exitNodes) the agent is closest to.

How do I transform the list of gateways into a list of exit nodes?
I tried

```
List<Node> exitNodes = gateways.Select(gw => gw.Connections).Select(node => node);
```

and this

```
List<Node> exitNodes = gateways.Select(gw => gw.Connections.Select(node => node));
```

I get the error

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<Node>>'
>   to`System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: convert IEnumerable into ToList by adding ToList() at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `SelectMany`.

If you use `Select`, then you get a `Enumerable<List<Node>>`, with `SelectMany`, you get only a `List<Node>`

```
List<Node> exitNodes = gateways.SelectMany(gw => gw.Connections).Select(node => node).ToList();
```

The answer in this post explains the difference between `SelectMany` and `Select`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/959057/5056173

Comment: I don't understand why i get a list<list<node> though... i was expecting to get a list<node>... with the first select i select the list from the gateway and with the second select i try to select the nodes from the lists

Comment: Please add the code to your answer, how you initialize your gateways variable and where you declare the variable, as well.

Comment: List<Node> gateways = new List<Node>();

also

class Node {
    public List<Node> Connections {get; set;} = new List<Node>();
...
}

Comment: I have updated my answer.. Use SelectMANY instead of Select

Comment: I still get an error... error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Node>' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<Node>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

actually i don't really need a List<Node>... IEnumerable<Node> works as well :-)