# C# LINQ - Return a typed filtered list based on a child property that is inside another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given the Objects :

```
class Parent
{
    private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private List<Child> childrenList;

    public List<Child> ChildrenList
    {
        get { return childrenList; }
        set { childrenList = value; }
    }
}

class Child
{
    private int idSub;

    public int IdSub
    {
        get { return idSub; }
        set { idSub = value; }
    }

    private bool isST;

    public bool IsST
    {
        get { return isST; }
        set { isST = value; }
    }
}
```

I have a `List<Parent> parentList = new List<Parent>()` and inside `Parent` object there is a list of `Child` which is called ChildrenList.

`Child` has a property `IsST`.

I want to return only the `Child` which has the property `IsST` equals true and if the `Parent` doesn't satisfy the condition, doesn't need to be returned.

And both lists returned, need to be typed with its respectively types.

What I have so far:

```
List<Parent> parentList = new List<Parent>()
{
    new Parent()
    {
        Id = 1,
        ChildrenList = new List<Child>()
        {
           new Child()
           {
               IdSub = 1,
               IsST = true
           },
           new Child()
           {
               IdSub = 2,
               IsST = true
           }
        }
    },
     new Parent()
    {
        Id = 2,
        ChildrenList = new List<Child>()
        {
           new Child()
           {
               IdSub = 3,
               IsST = false
           },
           new Child()
           {
               IdSub = 4,
               IsST = true
           }
        }
    },
     new Parent()
    {
        Id = 3,
        ChildrenList = new List<Child>()
        {
           new Child()
           {
               IdSub = 5,
               IsST = false
           },
           new Child()
           {
               IdSub = 6,
               IsST = false
           }
        }
    }
};


var parentFilteredList = parentList
            .Select(c => c.ChildrenList
                            .Where(d => d.IsST)
                            .ToList())
            .ToList();
```

But the list of parents in the `parentFilteredList` it's not of type `List<Parent>`.

[image: Result_so_far]

I need it to be `List<Parent>` because the `Parent` object in the real case there are a lot of properties, as well as the `Child`. `Select new` it's not an option.

Any help?

Comment: what do you mean _I need it to be typed_, currently `parentFilteredList` is of type `List<List<Child>>` , I am assuming you want a `List<Parent>` instead?

Comment: Are you looking to return all the parents where at least one child's ST is true? `var parentFilteredList = parentList.Where(c => c.ChildrenList.Any(d => d.IsST)).ToList();` Or do you want to also filter the children's list inside these parents?

Comment: @ZoharPeled might be just me but the more I read the description the more I think the OP wants `parentList
                .Select(c => new Parent
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    ChildrenList = c.ChildrenList
                                    .Where(d => d.IsST)
                                    .ToList()
            }).Where(p => p.ChildrenList.Count >= 1).ToList()` ?

Comment: @Aominè your code works fine, but I don't want to create a new `Parent` because in the real scenario `Parent` has a lot of properties, and this will cause me to fill all those properties manually.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I want to also filter the children's list inside these parents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking to return all the parents where at least one child's ST is true -

```
var parentFilteredList = parentList
     .Where(c => c.ChildrenList.Any(d => d.IsST))
     .ToList();
```

Or if you want to also filter the children's list inside these parents -

```
var parentFilteredList = parentList
     .Where(c => c.ChildrenList.Any(d => d.IsST))
     .Select(c => 
         {
             c.ChildrenList = c.ChildrenList.Where(d => d.IsST).ToList();
             return c;
         }).ToList();
```

Note that this will effect your original parents - I'm not sure that's a desirable outcome.

Comment: It works perfectly! Just for curiosity, how would I not effect the original parents? Because with this code the second child of the second parent is missing.

Comment: To not effect the original objects you need to create new ones in the select.

Answer (score 4):

```
var parentFilteredList = parentList
            .Select(c => c.ChildrenList
                            .Where(d => d.IsST)
                            .ToList())
            .ToList();
```

In the following statement you are selecting the childrenList.

```
var parentFilteredList = parentList
        .Where(c => c.ChildrenList.Any(d => d.IsST)).ToList();
```

Comment: That statement returns the parent which has two children, one with the property IsST equals true and the other child with property IsST equals false. Actually I want to filter children which only has the property IsST equals true.

Comment: You will have to use `All` instead of `Any`.

Comment: This way it only returns the parents  whose all children has the property IsST equals true, whereas I want the parents which have at least one child with that property true, btw filtering the children as well.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to use [SelectMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany), but there are a couple wrinkles depending on assumptions.

Basic code:

```
var list = parents.SelectMany
(
    p => p.ChildrenList.Where( c => c.IsST )
);
```

The above assumes there are 0 or 1 children per parent that match. If you want to handle the case where a parent has two or more matching children, you'll need one of the variants below.

If you want to throw an exception if a parent has two or more children that match:

```
var list = parents.SelectMany
(
    p => p.ChildrenList.Single( c => c.IsST )
);
```

If you want to exclude parents that have two children that match:

```
var list = parents.SelectMany
(
    p => p.ChildrenList.SingleOrDefault( c => c.IsST )
    ??   Enumerable.Empty<Child>()
);
```

If you want to include the first child that matches:

```
var list = parents.SelectMany
(
    p => p.ChildrenList
          .Where( c => c.IsST )
          .Take(1)
);
```

Comment: The first and the last snippets return a List<Child>, I need to return a List<Parent>.  Take a look at the accepted anwser(@Zohar Peled), which works as expected.

Comment: Thanks Bruno but I think the issue here, as with many software problems, was clear understanding of the requirements.

Comment: I see, sorry for not making myself clear, tks for helping the community.