# How to shorten my objects by using SelectMany?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have class Contact:

```
 public class Contact
    {
    public string Function { get; set; };

    public string Civility { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }


    public List<Certification> Certifications { get; set; } = new List<Certification>();

}
```

My query logic is as follows:

```
List<Contact> contacts
                  = await Context.Database
                                         .SqlQuery<Contact>("[dbo].[Contact] @codes,@Sprache",
                                         parameters).ToListAsync();
```

How to use .selectMany fot have olny names of functions of this class?

Comment: How many records are there in your db? If there are 15, why do you want 9?

Comment: I have 15 but there are duplicates (Sylvain x2, Clémence x3) ...

Comment: Thats because one is `Certification Officer` and the other is `Sales Officer`. They are completely different records with different ids. If you just want their names, then change your query and only get `distinct` last name.

Comment: no I need 1 list of FunctionsOOP and 1 list of pk_PrestaOOP. For example : for Stéphanie I need 1 lastName, 1 firstNam, 1 list of Function = { "Certification Officer","Sales Officer") and 1 list of pk_PrestaOOP = {"6DD....", "F6C...","EB6..."}, 1 email and 1 n° tel

Comment: You data model should be normalized. One contact should be related to multiple function records. Until you do that you'll never be able to get a list of distinct contacts easily. It'll even be harder to get data related to one contact, for example all `Certifications` one contact has.

Comment: You could use `GroupBy` to merge the duplicate records, but it is a bad idea to create a new `Contact` that does not match a record in the database, so you would have to return a new class or an anonymous object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want distinct objects why not use [Distinct()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-2.0). From my understand Select Many will flatten (aka reduce the nested collections) a collection. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany) out

Comment: and what is a result of "flatten a this collection" ?  (I try to understend Select Many)

Comment: @ElzbietaIgual Please see the example linked in my answer. You'll notice that the IEnumerable<IEnumerable<PhoneNumber>> is converted to just an IEnumerable<PhoneNumber>