# What's wrong with SelectMany?

Tags: c#, linq

I've encountered an issue with the SelectMany expression that I just can't wrap my head around.

Consider this: I have a collection of objects of this class

```
class Tag
{
    string DisplayText { get; set; }
    string Key { get; set; }
    int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm trying to get all my display texts (actually part of a much more complex expression):

```
var texts = AvailableTags.SelectMany(t => t.DisplayText);
```

Now why does this return me an `IEnumerable<char>` instead of an `IEnumerable<string>`??? Am I missing something?

Comment: it returns `IEnumerable<char>` because a string is a collection of chars

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany.  In particular, search for "list 'Fruits' contains 'apple'" in one of the answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `AvailableTags` is a list (an IEnumerable) then you should simply use

```
var texts = AvailableTags.Select(t => t.DisplayText);
```

The "strange" result you have using `SelectMany` is due (exactly as said from @derloopkat) to the fact that a string is a collection of char.
So you can imagine your code like this:

```
class Tag
{
    List<char> DisplayText { get; set; }
    string Key { get; set; }
    int Value { get; set; }
}
```

When you use `SelectMany` you're getting all the chars contained in every `DisplayText` and then the result is flattened.