# Access parent property in LINQ query using c#

Tags: c#, linq, parent-child

I want to access the following in **C#** using **LINQ**:

```
var output = db.AuditLogDetails.Where(c => c.CostCenterID == id).Select(m => new History
{
    CostCenterID=(int)m.CostCenterID,
    CostCenterOwner=c.Owner // c is not accesible
});
```

I am unable to assign `CostCenterOwner=c.Owner`

Comment: Try `m.Owner` c is unavailable since you have a `Select`.

Comment: Can you show us Class `AuditLogDetails`, `Owner` is a property of `AuditLogDetails`? if yes then `c` used in where clause predicate indicates single `AuditLogDetail` class and its scope is limited to **only** `where` clause. As you are doing `Select` after that you, now your `m` variable in `Select` referring single object of `AuditLogDetail` class. Instead of `c` you should use `m`.(c is not in scope of `Select`)

Comment: you should use a `join`

Comment: Dear Prasad, as commented in the below answer, I am repeating, Owner is a property of `c` not `m`. Do I have to use `SelectMany`? Show me.

Comment: `.Where` points to the same objects as `.Select` only filtered by where. Where doesn't change the objects types. So in this case `m == c`

Comment: @Charles so why doesn't c# allow me to use  `c` ?

Comment: Please share the class implementations.

Comment: @Sujoy It doesn't allow you to use c because c is in a different scope. c is a local variable for the `Where` function. Also `Select` is not a child of `where` you're just chaining two methods of an ienumerable.

Comment: @Charles now I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

`Where` clause just `Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate`, then you are selecting value in `Select` clause with `m` predicate

So you can try this way

```
.Select(m => new History
{
    CostCenterID=(int)m.CostCenterID,
    CostCenterOwner= m.Owner
});
```

Comment: It's the same, `Where` clause just `Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate`, then you are selecting value in `Select` clause with `m` predicate

Comment: @Sujoy he(Anonymous) is correct. `c` is equal to `m`. That is a fair assumption.

Comment: @Sujoy have you tried the suggested edit? If yes please provide feedback on this. We have very clearly explained why `m` is `c`. You have a `Select`! If it is not working it is because we do not have the full picture of your code! So please provide! The assumption is 100% valid `c` == `m` -> true.

Comment: @Sujoy could you pls share your class ?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to give us your `AuditLogDetails` class. Maby you need to use `SelectMany` instead.

Comment: @Anonymous can you please share the syntax using `SelectMany`, don't have the concept of `SelectMany`.

Comment: Why dont you give us your  `AuditLogDetails` class structure? [Sample for using `SelectMany`](https://linqsamples.com/linq-to-objects/projection/SelectMany)

Comment: @Sujoy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany

Comment: Does this answer your question? @Sujoy Let me know if you need any help.