# How to select values which are inside list of list in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a list of the object inside a list. I want a list of objects based on some condition.

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>> {
    new List<int> {1, 2, 3},
    new List<int> {4, 5, 6},
    new List<int> {7, 8, 9},
};
```

If I do something like

```
lists.Select(x => x.Where(y => y < 5));
```

I will get a `List<List<int>>`

But, I actually want List.
How can I get all the elements smaller than 5 as a `List<int>`?

PS: I know I can use for loop, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference Between Select and SelectMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany)

Comment: Now, it makes sense after reading the answer. I was not sure how to use Where() with SelectMany(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize SelectMany function provided by linq

```
var result = lists.SelectMany(x => x).Where(y => y < 5).ToList();
```

Comment: This is good. Thanks!