# convert List<IEnumerable<int>> to List<int> in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

¡Hi! I need help for this problem. When I do a request the result give me is IEnumerable. I need to convert this IEnumerable to List. This code resolve my problem but i'm looking for another alternative for resolve my problem more elegant than this.

```
   var folderCategoriesIds = FolderRepository.GetAll().Where(c => folderIds.Any(y => y == c.Id)).Select(x => x.Categories.Select(y => y.Id)).ToList();
   List<int> list = new List<int>();
   foreach (var item in folderCategoriesIds)
   {
       list.AddRange(item.ToList());
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `SelectMany()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13035259/1064169

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten lists. Just add `.SelectMany(x => x)` before `ToList()` and it will work