# C# Generic collections - Get list of sub level child items from parent object

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have parent object which contain List and this child1 has List , I would like to get the List items as return type when I pass Parent object as input parameter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buMt7.png)

Comment: Please do not include a screenshot of code. Please include the relevant code directly in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference Between Select and SelectMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany)

Comment: you can use `.SelectMany` to flatten grandchildren objects. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.SelectMany` to flatten grandchildren objects. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0