# How can I get EF to Select and only return selected columns

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

This is my code
[image]

```
 public IEnumerable<InsightPost> InsightsPosts { get; set; }
 public void OnGet()
 {
      InsightsPosts = _db.InsightPosts.Where(p => p.Tags.Contains("test")).SelectMany(s => new { s.Title, s.Description });
 }
```

My database has more columns but I only need a select few. What am I doing wrong here.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using Select instead of SelectMany?

Comment: yep it says to use selectmany

Comment: @Zippy you dont need use selectmany, can use .Select(s => new {s.Title, s.Desc}). [difference between Select and SelectMany difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define the model you need property as follow

```
public class PostModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

after you can use it in select statement

```
InsightsPosts = _db.InsightPosts.Where(p => p.Tags.Contains("test"))
                .Select(s => new PostModel{ Title =s.Title, Description = s.Description })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an result model for your method.

```
public class FullModel
{
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

public class ResultModel
{
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
var results = lista.Where(p => p.PropertyOne == "one").Select(p => new ResultModel()
{
    PropertyOne = p.PropertyOne,
});
```

then only result model properties will exists on result

```
[{"PropertyOne":"one"}]
```