# Entity Framework added s to my .dbo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I using "Entity Framework DbContext" at the moment I have got exception towars.dbo was not found. This is very strange because in my website I all the time ask about towar.dbo but no towars.dbo Do you know where is a problem?

```
- InnerException    {"Invalid object name 'dbo.Towars'."}   System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}
```

My all things about Towar (of course different place in my program):

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Product/
        public ITowarRepository repository;

        public ProductController(ITowarRepository productRepository) 
        {
        repository = productRepository;
        }

        public ViewResult List()
        {
            return View(repository.Towar);
        }

}


public interface ITowarRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Towar> Towar { get; }
    }

public DbSet<Towar> Towar { get; set; }

public class EFTowarRepository : ITowarRepository
    {
        public EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
        public IQueryable<Towar> Towar
        {
            get { return context.Towar; }
        }
    }
public class Towar
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id_tow { get; set; }
        public string Nazwa { get; set; }
        public string Opis { get; set; }
        public decimal Cena { get; set; }
        public int Id_kat { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: what is your table name in the db ? ARe you connected to the correct db ?

Comment: connection do database is correct   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=RAF\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sklep_Baza;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can tell EF to map to the table `Towar` by overriding the `OnModelCreating` method in your `DBContext` class with fluent API like this:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Towar>().ToTable("Towar");
   }
}
```

Now EF will look for `Towar` table instead of `Towars`. If you do not have these tables created, there is some other problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks for help :) I don't understand why they create this stupid thing in Visual Studio but I`am very glad for your help.

Answer (score 14):

Add the following line to your context:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Comment: This is the best way because the other solutions are only a one time fix.

Answer (score 6):

EF Code First automatically pluralizes the table names. Use a `[Table]` attribute to explicitly map the entity to a table name:

```
[Table("Towary")]
public class Towary
{
   // Whatever properties
}
```

It looks like there's a way to disable pluralization gobally too, see [Entity Framework Code First naming conventions - back to plural table names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425027/entity-framework-code-first-naming-conventions-back-to-plural-table-names).

Comment: Error 1 'Name' is not a valid named attribute argument. Named attribute arguments must be fields which are not readonly, static, or const, or read-write properties which are public and not static. C:\Users\Rafal\Desktop\MVC ksiązka\moj projekt\sklep\SportsStore\Entities\Product.cs 9 12 SportsStore.Domain

Comment: Sorry, I read the wrong docs. It should be just `[Table("Towary")]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace MVCDemo.Models

     {
         public class EmployeeContext : DbContext

         protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
         {
             modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
         }
}
```

For the sake of completeness @forty-two

Comment: With your response @Crismogram, I am able to connect to a remote database without any problems.... Great aproach...