# Invalid object name using code first Entity Framework on database table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework code-first migrations. And I created a migration to change the name of a table in my database:

```
public partial class ChangeNameOfCodePerformanceAnchorTable : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.Code_PerformanceAnchor", newName: "CodePerformanceAnchor");
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.CodePerformanceAnchors", newName: "Code_PerformanceAnchor");
    }
}
```

Now, when I create the controller for that table.. on the Index action I have this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.CodePerformanceAnchor.Include(c => c.CodePhase).ToList());
}
```

When I run the application to get to that specific index page, I get this error:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.CodePerformanceAnchors'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.CodePerformanceAnchors'.

The only thing in my application that is called `CodePerformanceAnchors` is the controller.  The model is `CodePerformanceAnchor`.

```
public virtual DbSet<CodePerformanceAnchor> CodePerformanceAnchor { get; set; }
```

Any help on resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Pluralization](https://edspencer.me.uk/2012/03/13/entity-framework-plural-and-singular-table-names/) is the default. Check the actual name of the table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 names for table:

CodePerformanceAnchor

and 

CodePerformanceAnchors (additional s at the end)

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425027/entity-framework-code-first-naming-conventions-back-to-plural-table-names) (Pluggable Conventions) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799180/entity-framework-added-s-to-my-dbo) (specifying table name)

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.. how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you changed `ChangeNameOfCodePerformanceAnchorTable` since creating it? Up method uses `CodePerformanceAnchor` why Down method uses `CodePerformanceAnchors`. Erorr seems to be thrown when Down is invoked.