# Entity Framework migration error rename table

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I tried to add new model to my project with code-first migration.
The model looks like this:

```
public class Renting
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string RequesterEmail { get; set; }
    public string RequesterName { get; set; }

    public int RoomNumber{ get; set; }
    public RentalOption RentalOption { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

the User and Rentaloption will connect these tables.
I added a migration, then I tried to update-database from 'package manager console'.

then I got an error message:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (112ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      EXEC sp_rename N'[User]', N'Users';
Failed executing DbCommand (112ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
EXEC sp_rename N'[User]', N'Users';
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Error: The new name 'Users' is already in use as a object name and would cause a duplicate that is not permitted.
```

I did not changed the User model. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

the entity framework automatically pluralize the table names : User will become Users

check this link ..

[Entity Framework Code First naming conventions - back to plural table names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425027/entity-framework-code-first-naming-conventions-back-to-plural-table-names)

do this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

you can give table names like this: (in OnModelCreating() )

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
```

Comment: okey, its not problem. the problem is like update-database try to recreate table, despite of if its already exists.

Comment: I think your problem is that you have auto migrations turned on. You need to disable it. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667172/how-can-i-disable-migration-in-entity-framework-6-0