# LinQ to Entities: Query with five tables JOIN

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities

I have five tables all with a primary key of ID

- User
- User_Role_Relation with Foreign Keys User_ID and Role_ID
- Role
- Role_Right_Relation with Foreign Keys Role_ID and Right_ID
- Right

I am currently getting the Rights for the selected User with the following query in a stored procedure

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
      tbl_Right.ID, tbl_Right.Name    
  FROM 
      tbl_User_Role_Relation 
  INNER JOIN 
      tbl_Role_Right_Relation ON tbl_User_Role_Relation.Role_ID =  tbl_Role_Right_Relation.Role_ID 
  INNER JOIN 
      tbl_Right ON tbl_Role_Right_Relation.Right_ID = tbl_Right.ID
  WHERE 
      tbl_User_Role_Relation.User_ID = @User_ID
```

I am trying to covert this to LINQ to Entity with this code

```
var query = from r in context.Rights
            from rrr in r.Role_Right_Relation
            from rl in rrr.Role
            from urr in rl.User_Role_Relation
            where urr.User_ID == userid
            select r;
```

but I get the following error

> An expression of type 'Models.Role' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'

Any advise would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all that linq query is doing a cross join, not inner join like your sql. You should check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql)

Second of all, you would probably be best correctly defining the relationships between entities in the edmx and you probably won't have to join at all, instead you can use [navigation properites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738520.aspx) to access parent/children and filter on those properties directly

The idea of the entity framework is you don't have to flatten the hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 3**

If you posted your code verbatim, then you are missing a line

```
from u in urr.Users
```

So:

```
var query = from r in context.Rights
from rrr in r.Role_Right_Relation
from rl in rrr.Role
from urr in rl.User_Role_Relation
from u in urr.Users
where u.User_ID == userid
select r;
```

Or at least there's a typo and the where should read:

```
where urr.User_ID == userid
```

resulting in:

```
var query = from r in context.Rights
from rrr in r.Role_Right_Relation
from rl in rrr.Role
from urr in rl.User_Role_Relation
where urr.User_ID == userid
select r;
```

Comment: what  I posted had a typo.  I have corrected the post but I am still getting the error.   I get the error on the line with: from rl in  rrr.Role

Answer (score 0):

If you use method syntax you should be able to do something like:

```
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
var rights =user.Roles.SelectMany(role => role.Rights).Distinct();
```

Be sure to check user is not null before getting rights