# Entity Framework Query for inner join

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What would be the query for:

```
select s.* from Service s 
inner join ServiceAssignment sa on sa.ServiceId = s.Id
where  sa.LocationId = 1
```

in entity framework?

This is what I wrote:

```
 var serv = (from s in db.Services
                join sl in Location on s.id equals sl.id
                where sl.id = s.id
                select s).ToList();
```

but it's wrong. Can some one guide me to the path?

Comment: Look there : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: You are using assignment `=` instead of comparison `==` in `where` clause. Also you don't need that if you already joined on that fields.

Comment: Isn't `where sl.id = s.id` redundant with your join condition?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
from s in db.Services
join sa in db.ServiceAssignments on s.Id equals sa.ServiceId
where sa.LocationId == 1
select s
```

Where `db` is your `DbContext`. Generated query will look like (sample for EF6):

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
       -- other fields from Services table
FROM [dbo].[Services] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ServiceAssignments] AS [Extent2]
    ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[ServiceId]
WHERE [Extent2].[LocationId] = 1
```

Comment: Isn't that a left outer join?

Comment: @JonathanWood No, that is inner join. Left outer join will be generated by group join.

Comment: Could we use from s in db.Services
join sa in db.ServiceAssignments on s.Id equals sa.ServiceId **|| s.Id equals null**
where sa.LocationId == 1
select s

Comment: Many thanks... I've used `List<Item> items = (..your code..).toList();`

Comment: @JoSmo if you have a navigation property (from example below) you can use Method syntax no problem. But if not, it would look like this (pretty hairy):
`db.Services.Join(db.ServiceAssignments, s=>s.Id, sa=>sa.ServiceId, (s,sa)=> new{service = s, alert=sa}).Where(ssa=>ssa.alert.LocationId ==1).Select(ssa=>ssa.service);`

Answer (score 73):

In case anyone's interested in the Method syntax, if you have a navigation property, it's way easy:

```
db.Services.Where(s=>s.ServiceAssignment.LocationId == 1);
```

If you don't, unless there's some `Join()` override I'm unaware of, I think it looks pretty gnarly (and I'm a Method syntax purist):

```
db.Services.Join(db.ServiceAssignments, 
     s => s.Id,
     sa => sa.ServiceId, 
     (s, sa) => new {service = s, asgnmt = sa})
.Where(ssa => ssa.asgnmt.LocationId == 1)
.Select(ssa => ssa.service);
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the FK to ServiceAssignment happened to be nullable, would it?

Comment: @Cardin in that case I would suggest the C#6 ?. operator. If you don't have that, just check for null before using the navigation property. Generally, you don't add a bunch of defensive code in examples, so as not to confuse the primary point. If the FK is nullable, it would look like this: (C#6)
`db.Services.Where(s=>s?.ServiceAssignment.LocationId == 1);`
or like this in C#5:
`db.Services.Where(s=>s.ServiceAssignment != null && s.ServiceAssignment.LocationId == 1);`

Comment: @MichaelBlackburnThat's true! It is more understandable. Thanks for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 8):

You could use a navigation property if its available. It produces an inner join in the SQL.

```
from s in db.Services
where s.ServiceAssignment.LocationId == 1
select s
```