# Entity Framework Sqlite syntax

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

What kind of entity framwork syntax can i use to achieve a basic sql statement?

In my old code i just did:

```
        String query = @"   select Equipment.EquipmentTag, EquipmentExtension.ExtensionDescription, Equipment.Description, Equipment.Area, ObjectTypes.TypeName 
                            from Equipment, EquipmentExtension, ObjectTypes
                            where Equipment.EquipmentId = EquipmentExtension.EquipmentID AND EquipmentExtension.ObjectTypeId = ObjectTypes.Id";

        sql.CommandText = query;
        SQLiteDataReader reader = sql.ExecuteReader();
```

I have tried the equivalent of "select * from equipment":

```
  var db = new norsokdbEntities();
  var equipmentList = from eq in db.Equipment
  select eq;
```

But I dont see how i can modify this kind of syntax to join multiple tables.
Any thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16025457/1707033 -> this is what you must do...

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framwork-join-3-tables

Comment: var equipmentList = from eq in db.Equipment
                                join ee in db.EquipmentExtension on eq.EquipmentId equals ee.EquipmentID
                                select eq ;
It only returns fields from the first table. I want to select a couple of fields from each table.

Comment: you must join them properly...do not try to select like you did in sql... or you can apply a simple select on a view...

Comment: I am joining them by primary key "EquipmentId" in Equipment and foreign key "EquipmentId" in EquipmentExtension. I think that is "properly". Now I want to display the result of the join to the user in a DataGridView. The link you provided is only for columns from one table..... As you can see i want to  display the Equipment and all extensions. What is wrong with 
"SELECT * FROM Equipment, EquipmentExtension 
WHERE Equipment.EquipmentId = EquipmentExtension.EquipmentId?