# Perform inner join in LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need join in LINQ query, I have done individually but struggling to do in one process.

### SQL Script

```
SELECT af.submission_id, af.created_date, af.surname,af.first_name
FROM app_forms af
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM sync_audit_log sal WHERE sal.log_Status='EP' AND sal.lookup_id IS NULL AND id=(SELECT Max(id) FROM sync_audit_log sal2 WHERE  sal.submission_id=sal2.submission_id)) sal ON sal.submission_id=af.submission_id 
LEFT JOIN ebs_sync es ON af.submission_id=es.submission_id
WHERE es.person_code IS NULL
```

### LINQ

```
 var query = (from af in _uof.Web_AppFormsRepository.GetAll()
                         select af).ToList();

 var query2 = (from sal in _uof.Web_SyncAuditLogRepository.GetAll().Where(sal => sal.LOG_STATUS.Equals("EP") && sal.LOOKUP_ID!=null )
                          select sal.ID).ToList();

 var query3 = (from sal2 in _uof.Web_SyncAuditLogRepository.GetAll()
                          select new { sal2.ID }).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you working on EF? This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16025457/1050927

Comment: yes I am and my database is in Oracle 11g

Comment: ... `join`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should understand that when you call ToList() EF do request to Database, I mean now you do 3 independent requests to db instead of only one. Call ToList only when you ready to execute one main query.

And about join [Linq has join operator just use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql) 
You can use sql like  syntax or expression syntax
 [see this question for examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: I am well aware ToList hits database.... I keep linq script to understand behavior and result from each

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<T> leftInnerJoin = from i in left join j in right on i.condition equals j.condition select i;

IEnumerable<T> leftOuterJoin = from i in left join j in right on i.condition equals j.condition into grp from k in grp.DefaultIfEmpty() where k == null select i;

IEnumerable<T> rightOuterJoin = from i in right join j in left on i.condition equals j.condition into grp from k in grp.DefaultIfEmpty() where k == null select i;

IEnumerable<T> groupJoin = leftOuterJoin.Union(rightOuterJoin).Union(leftInnerJoin);
```