# How can I get build a query based on array of IDs using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to build a query selecting all records containing IDs which are stored in the list using that code:

```
var assistsIds = _context.Assistances.Where(c => c.IdUser == user.IdUser)
                        .Select(x => x.Owner.IdOwner).ToList();
```

Then I'm going through all the list elements to get a query:

```
var query = _context.Accounts.Where(_ => _.IsDeleted != 1);

                foreach(var assist in assistsIds)
                {
                    query = query.Where(_ => _.IdOwner == assist);
                }
```

The result is that I'm getting something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE IdOwner = 1 AND IdOwner = 2 ...etc
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE IdOwner = 1 OR IdOwner = 2 ... etc
```

Is there a way to apply OR operator, or maybe there is some other way to achieve that?

Comment: Maybe what you need is something like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16025457/2494218

Comment: A where on top of a where, logically, is an AND. A where alongside a where, would be an OR, but calling where on the result of a where is "on top", not "alongside"

Comment: Do you have navigation properties set up so you can navigate eg Assistance.Owner.Accounts?

Comment: .AnyAsync is equivalent to Or in SQL

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-6.0):

```
var query = _context.Accounts
                .Where(_ => _.IsDeleted != 1 && assistsIds.Contains(_.IdOwner));
```

This will return all records which match an Id in the `assistsIds` list.