# C# LINQ Join multiple tables into one object

Tags: c#, linq, join

Main problem to solve:

**How do I get "2 levels down" to get Owner.Pet[n].Toys and put it all in one object right away.**

There are three entities in the system: `Owner`, `Pet` and `Toy`.

I am trying to write a query (using LINQ's SQL-like notation) that will bring me single object of class `Owner` with its inner properties filled = **all pets assigned to that owner + each pet having all its toys.**

This is what I have so far, it's not working as expected. SQL feelings tell me that I am missing GROUP JOIN somewhere...

```cs
var singleOwnerQuery =
    from o in owners
    join p in pets on o.FirstName = p.OwnerName
    join t in toys on p.PetId = t.ToyUniqueId // each toy is unique - there are not "re-usable" toys 
    where o.Name == "..." && o.LastName == "..."
    select new Owner
    {
        Pets = pets // this should already assign all the toys for each of the pets
    };
```

Any help will be appreciated.

*I skipped lot of other properties inside each of the classes to make it simpler*

Comment: The relationship between pets and owners is confusing. You're joining on a string (Name) yet pets has a PK (PetId). Why not join pets and owners by the PKs (PetId, OwnerId)?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677871/c-sharp-joining-3-lists-with-linq

Comment: There is an example for owners and pets doing exactly this here: [Example - Group join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins#example---group-join).

Comment: You say it's not working as expected, but what is not working? Is it not filling the  `Pets`  correctly? Have you tested the base query to make sure it correctly retrieves the data you are looking for?

Comment: If you expect correct query as an answer, ALWAYS show your model with navigation properties.

Comment: There are no navigation properties, because there are no FK in a db.  If there would be FKs - I would mention it. I could also use EF Core and all of its fency stuff. but sadly -  "ain't no navigation properties"

Comment: @GHDevOps - it's irrelevant in my question - I did not state my problem as not being able to join two tables

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. Without model, this is just direction how to do Eager Loading query as in your case.

```cs
var singleOwnerQuery =
    from o in owners
    where o.Name == "..." && o.LastName == "..."
    select new Owner
    {
        Pets = pets.Where(p => o.FirstName == p.OwnerName)
          .Select(p => new 
          {
              p.PetId,
              Toys = toys.Where(t => p.PetId == t.ToyUniqueId).ToList()
          })
          .tolist()
    };
```