# How to perform inner join Query in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I Have three tables and I need to perform inner join query for LINQ using C#. I can go half way but i am very beginner, need help in that many thanks

### SQL Query

```
Select O.CarID, C.customerID, C.Name, C.Address, V.Brand, V.Model, V.Model_Year 
FROM Car_OwnerShip As O, Customers As C, Cars As V
WHERE V.CarID = O.CarID AND O.customerID = C.customerID AND C.Name='toxic';
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: you could have easily found this answer googling. an inner join is the easiest join in linq or sql to do.

Answer (score 5):

I think that something like this will do the trick:

```
Car_Ownership
.Join
(
    Customers,
    o=>o.customerID,
    c=>c.customerID,
    (o,c)=>new{o,c}
)
.Join
(
    Cars,
    o=>o.o.CarId,
    v=>v.CarID,
    (o,v)=>new{o,v}
)
.Where
(
    x=>
    x.o.c.Name == "toxic"
)
.Select
(
    x=>
    new
    {
        CarID = x.o.o.CarID,
        customerID = x.o.c.customerID,
        Name = x.o.c.Name,
        Address = x.o.c.Address,
        Brand = x.v.Brand,
        Model = x.v.Model,
        Model_Year = x.v.Model_Year
    }
)
```

Comment: Talk about a verbose query... Very educational, though.

Comment: @usr I used to hate and not understand Lambdas. They actually had my head nearly explode trying to think how they work. When i got it i just can't think of anything else...

Comment: Should that be `(o,v)=>new{o,v}` in the second Join..

Comment: @DogEars Thanks for the Edit...I was blind when i fixed it in the first place.

Comment: @jyparask no worries.. impressive that it was so close without any testing!

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from owner in Car_OwnerShip
            from customer in Customers
            from car in Cars 
            select new { owner, customer, car }
            where owner.CarID = car.CarID and owner.CustomerID = customer.CustomerId and customer.Name = "toxic";
```

Comment: Although this probably works I would not agree with the where-based join style.

Comment: it is giving me error!

Comment: its possible because i didn't testing that, what error you got?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
from o in Car_OwnerShip
join c in Customers on o.customerID equals c.customerID
join v in Cars on o.CarID equals v.CarID 
where c.Name=='toxic'
select new {
O.CarID, C.customerID, C.Name, C.Address, V.Brand, V.Model, V.Model_Year 
}
```