# Query objects for one to many relationship in LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq, group-by, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have a problem which seems to be quite similar to
[Query objects for one to many relationship in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669802/query-and-create-objects-with-a-one-to-many-relationship-using-linq)

I've been trying to solve my problem referring the above but somehow I've been failing for a long time.

**The scenario**
I have a model named Business which has a ICollection of Branches and also the business belongs to a particular **SubCategory**.

The model Looks something like

```
public class SubCategory
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public string Category_FK { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubCategory_FK")]
    public ICollection<Business> Businesses { get; set; }

    public SubCategory(){
        Businesses = new Collection<Business>();
    }
}

public class Business
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string HeadquartersContact { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }

    public string SubCategory_FK { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Business_Fk")]
    public ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }

    public Business()
    {
        Branches = new Collection<Branch>();
    }
}
```

And the Branch Model Looks like

```
public class Branch
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public Business Business { get; set; }

    public string Business_Fk { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Location_FK")]
    public Location Location { get; set; }

    public string Location_FK { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Branch_FK")]
    public ICollection<BranchImage> BranchImages { get; set; }

    public Branch()
    {
        BranchImages = new Collection<BranchImage>();
    }
}
```

Every branch can have one location. So below is the Location Model

```
public class Location
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public decimal Lattitude { get; set; }

        public decimal Longitude { get; set; }

        public SubLocality SubLocality { get; set; }

        public string SubLocality_FK { get; set; }

        public Branch Branch { get; set; }

        public Location()
        {
        }
    }
```

A SubLocality Can have ICollection of Locations. Here is the SubLocality Model

```
public class SubLocality
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Locality Locality { get; set; }

    public string Locality_FK { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubLocality_FK")]
    public ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    public SubLocality()
    {
        Locations = new Collection<Location>();
    }


}
```

Localities can have ICollection of Sublocality

```
public class Locality
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public City City { get; set; }

    public string City_FK { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Locality_FK")]
    public ICollection<SubLocality> SubLocalities { get; set; }

    public Locality()
    {
        SubLocalities = new Collection<SubLocality>();
    }
}
```

A City can have ICollection of Localities.

```
public class City
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public State State { get; set; }

    public string State_FK { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("City_FK")]
    public ICollection<Locality> Localities { get; set; }

    public City()
    {
        Localities = new Collection<Locality>();
    }
}
```

And Lastly a state can have ICollection of cities.

```
public class State
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("State_FK")]
    public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }

    public State()
    {
        Cities = new Collection<City>();
    }
}
```

Here is my **DataContext** whose instances my am using in the query to fetch data.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options): base (options)
    {

    }

    //-------Business_Info_Models----------------
    public DbSet<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BranchImage> BranchImages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Business> Businesses { get; set; }

    //-------Category_Info_Models----------------
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

    //-------------Location_Info_Models----------------
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Locality> Localities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Location> Locations{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubLocality> SubLocalities { get; set; }
}
```

**The requirement**
Now I need to query for a businesses of a particular subcategory, and also get all the branches(like one business can have 8 branches, 5 branches etc). It's location, sublocation, city, state (To mention I get all this data from different tables by using join in LINQ).

To satisfy this requirement, I am using a DTO (Data Transfer Object).

```
public class AddBusinessDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string HeadquartersContact { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public string SubCategory_FK  { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AddBranchDto> Branches { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<AddLocationsDto> Locations {get; set; }
}

public class AddBranchDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public AddLocationsDto Location { get; set; }
    public string Location_FK { get; set; }
}
```

**The LINQ Query**

```
IQueryable<BusinessDto> query =  (from business in _context.Businesses
        join subcategory in _context.SubCategories on business.SubCategory_FK equals subcategory.Id
        join branch in _context.Branches on business.Id equals branch.Business_Fk 
        join location in _context.Locations on branch.Location_FK equals location.Id
        join sublocal in _context.SubLocalities on location.SubLocality_FK equals sublocal.Id
        join locality in _context.Localities on sublocal.Locality_FK equals locality.Id
        join city in _context.Cities on locality.City_FK equals city.Id
        join state in _context.States on city.State_FK equals state.Id
        where business.SubCategory_FK == subCatId
        select new BusinessDto() {
            Id = business.Id,
            Name = business.Name,
            HeadquartersContact = business.HeadquartersContact,
            Location = location.Name,
            Sublocality = sublocal.Name,
            Locality = locality.Name,
            City = city.Name,
            State = state.Name,
            Email = business.Email,

            Branches = business.Branches
                        .Select(branches => 
                        new BranchDto{Id = branches.Id, Name = branches.Name, Phone = branches.Phone})
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToList()
        });
```

I am almost there to the result but this the **BUG** with this query is :

[image: The buggy output]

The above business in the SS has 8 branches. Ideally I should ne getting just one card on th UI which shows data of 8 branches when I hover the branch icon.

But the query gives me 8 cards of such sort. How do I solve this. Pleae help!

Comment: Your model data and query does not match. Please update the full model.

Comment: @TanvirArjel updated the model and DataContext file.
Appreciate your help in advanced.

Comment: If you are using EF, why are you using `join` ?

Comment: @NetMage
Thats how we get data from multiplee tables rite?
EF has two syntax first is the method syntax and second is query syntax. So here  i am using the query syntax.

Any suggestions on how do I solve the mentioned problem.