# Get Data Reference Data In Razor Function

Tags: c1-cms

I have three Global Data Type 
 Tour 
 Hotel 
 Airline

I have Created A Razor Function To Display Tour With Relevant Hotel And  Airline Information 
 But I Cant Get Airline and Hotel Data In My Function Here Is the Code :

```
    @foreach (var Tour in Data.Get<Countries.Tour>())
{
     @Tour.Airline.Name 
    <img src='~/media(@Tour.Thumb)'  />
}
```

@Tour.Airline.Name is not working 
 I cant save the function 
 neither @Tour.Airline which only output the airline Guid not the airline name .

so what do you recommend ? using xslt function ? or creating helper function to pass airline Guid and get the airlone data back which I think make the system a bit complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C1 Data layer will return "a flat structure" consisting of simple fields (string, int, guid etc) and not a deep object structure.

You need to do join with the Airline type, something like this:

```
var myList = from tour in Data.Get<Countries.Tour>()
join airline in Data.Get<Countries.Airline>() on tour.Airline equals airline.Id
select new { airline.Name, tour.Thumb};

@foreach (var element in myList)
{
     @element.Name 
    <img src='~/media(@element.Thumb)'  />
}
```

See [What is the syntax for an inner join in LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql)