# Entity Framework inner join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

I have two tables something like this:

Customers:

- Email
- username

Products:

- Username
- Product

I'd like to fill a class with username, product, and email.

This is what I have so

```
var res = from H in db.Products
          join C in db.customers on H.Username equals C.Username
          where C.Username == H.Username
          select H;

Results results = res.Single();
```

However the catch is that I'm not sure exactly how this works, can anyone break it down for me?

Comment: What exactly is what you are unsure about? The .Single() or what results the query itself will give you,...?

Comment: As its an inner join it would give you only results that have values in both H and C (the where shouldn't be necessary as the join already has the appropriate value)  if you are unsure about the syntax for an inner join: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: @Thomas I'm wondering what values will I get back... for example will this populat the results class with Username Email and Product?

Comment: can I select H and C?

Comment: Updated my answer to also include why a step like a dto / anonymous type is necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var res = from H in db.Products
                      join C in db.customers on H.Username equals C.Username
                      where C.Username == H.Username
                      select H;

            Results results = res.Single();
```

The code above makes an inner join between C and H (the where clause is not necessary) and results in all elements given back where an appropriately connected products and customers entry exist.

The select H "just" gives back all the data from the products. As you stated that you want a mix you need to do that differently.

I myself would be using an anonymous type (or a dto object).
For an anonymous type:

```
select new { Username = H.Username, Product = H.Product, EMail = C.EMail}
```

Put together:

```
  var res = from H in db.Products
                      join C in db.customers on H.Username equals C.Username
                      where C.Username == H.Username
                      select new { Username = H.Username, Product = H.Product, EMail = C.EMail}

            Results results = res.Single();
```

For a DTO (Data Transfer Object) you would create a class with public set/get properties and use select new myClass(){....}  instead of the select new {}.

DTOs are better in terms of reuse and that you have less problems with writing the names wrong that you use, ....

---

*Just simply using select H, C  sadly can't work as Linq wants to return just single objects per row (and additionally always the same datatype). Thus you need to put a container around the objects you want to return. In this case either anonymous types or DTOs.*

Comment: Of course, the container can be as simple as `new { Product = H, Customer = C }`, pretty easy to work with.