# LINQ to SQL Join orderby

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, join, linq-to-sql

i am new to LINQ and joins, so Please forgive me if I am asking it wrong.
I have two tables

**Table1**

```
id   name    date
1    Mike    20-10-15
2    John    21-10-15
3    Sam     23-10-15
```

**Table2**

```
id   name   date
1    Ashle  19-10-15
2    Lily   21-10-15
3    Jeni   22-10-15
4    April  23-10-15
```

I need 5 records using Joins and should be orderby Date, most recent records.

Can you guys help me, I really need to figure out how Joins works with orderby.
Thanks

**EDIT:**
They are two different tables so no foreign key, so I think I can't use Join, so so far what I have done is like this

```
var combinddata = (from t1 in db.Table1
                        select t1.id)
                            .Concat(from t2 in db.Table2
                                    select t2.id);
```

I don't know how to get only 5 records how to compare records from both tables on DateTime base.

**Output should be**

1. Sam
2. April
3. Jeni
4. John
5. Lily

Comment: No you are NOT "asking it wrong" but you need to show first what you have already tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the syntax for an inner join in LINQ to SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: you have to use `Concat`. then `OrderByDescending` date. then `Take` first 5.

Comment: See webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: I edited the question, Can you guys please see it again. Thanks

Comment: What want you result above data specify in question

Comment: @MukeshKalgude: I updated the question with possible output. can you please check. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate equal anonymous types from different tables. If you also select the dates, you can sort by them, in descending order, and take the first 5 records:

```
Table1.Select (t1 => 
    new
    {
        Id = t1.Id,
        Name = t1.Name,
        Date = t1.Date
    }
).Concat(
Table2.Select (t2 => 
    new
    {
        Id = t2.Id,
        Name = t2.Name,
        Date = t2.Date
    }
))
.OrderByDescending (x => x.Date).Take(5)
```

Note that this gives precedence to items in `Table1`. If item 5 and 6 in the concatenated result are on the same date, but from `Table1` and `Table2`, respectively, you only get the item from `Table1`.

If you want, you can select only the names from this result, but I assume that your output only shows the intended order of record, not the exact expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = 
    from Table1 in table1
    join Table2 in table2 on table1.id equals table2.id 
    orderby table1.date ascending 
    select table1.date;
```

Comment: They are two different tables so no foreign key, so I think I can't use Join, so why are you use join....

Comment: @MukeshKalgude: I am sorry, actually I didn't mention it earlier and used Join in question title. Actually I wasn't sure what to use. Join or Concat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
var combinddata = (from t1 in db.Table1
                        select t1.Name)
                            .Concat(from t2 in  db.Table2 
                                    select t2.Name).OrderByDescending(x => x.date).Take(5);
```