# Linq select tablemapping(Entity framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following tables

```
**Track Table**
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| TrackId        | TrackName    |       Path         |
+===============+===============+====================+
| 1             | jb            | http://domain/1.mp3|
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| 2             | remix         | http://domain/2.mp3|
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+

**Favorite Table**
    +---------------+---------------+--------------------+
    | favoriteId    | ProfileId     |       TrackId      |
    +===============+===============+====================+
    | 10            | 2130          | 1                  |
    +---------------+---------------+--------------------+
    | 11            | 2132          | 2                  |
    +---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

I need to select tracks into a model where I have to include a boolean field `IsFavorite`.
Right now my logic is as follows:

```
1.Select Tracks
2.Select all favorites by profile
3.Iterate to both list and fill field "IsFavorite"
```

Is there any better method that can work out the same?

Following is my current logic code

```
Var ActiveTracks = jukeboxTrackService.GetActiveTracks();
var UserFavorites = jukeboxTrackService.GetFavoritesByProfile(ProfileId);
foreach (var item in ActiveTracks )
{
    foreach (var fav in UserFavorites)
    {
        if (item.JukeBoxTrackId == fav.TrackId)
        {
            item.IsFavorite = true;
        }
    }
}

return ActiveTracks ;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use inner join with linq http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 2):

```
(from tr in ActiveTracks 
join usrfav in UserFavorites on tr.TrackId equals usr.TrackId into UsrTracks
from usrtr in  UsrTracks.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new Track
{ 
  IsFavorite = (usrfav.TrackId == null) ? false : true 
}
```