# C# linq lambda join and select syntax

Tags: c#, linq, join, lambda

I'm looking for the counterpart of Msql query:

```
SELECT per.*,add.addressDescription FROM Persons per 
       JOIN Address add ON per.AddressId = add.AddressId
```

I have this query:

```
    var query = persons.JOIN(address,per = person.addressId,add = addressId
    (per,add) => 
    new Persons{
                addressDescription = add.addressDescription,
                PersonId = per.PersonId,
                PersonFirstName = per.PersonFirstName
                PersonLastName = per.PersonLastName})
```

Is there a way to populate `Persons.addressDescription` without assigning individually the other properties of `Persons`? Imagine if `Persons` have 10 more properties.

I would like to refrain from using loops like:

```
foreach(Person person in PersonList)
{
  foreach(Address address in AddressList)
  {
     if(person.addressId == address.addressId){
        person.addressDescription = address.addressDescription
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the syntax for an inner join in LINQ to SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: @shA.t hi and thanks for your reply, the problem is their question only asks how to return the Persons without populating Persons.AddressDescription.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = persons.join(address,
    per = person.addressId,
    add = addressId
    (per,add) => 
    {
        per.addressDescription = add.addressDescription;
        return per;
    });
```

Comment: wow really, thats the first time I saw a return in the select statement. I'll give it a go now.

Comment: I can't use return function inside the query =/

Comment: @user3770093 Show what you did because for me it works

Comment: Hi mate thanks your solution worked! I had simple typo errors. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
var id = 1;
var query = database.Posts    // your starting point - table in the "from" statement
   .Join(database.Post_Metas, // the source table of the inner join
      post => post.ID,        // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
      meta => meta.Post_ID,   // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
      (post, meta) => new { Post = post, Meta = meta }) // selection
   .Where(postAndMeta => postAndMeta.Post.ID == id);    // where statement
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I think I will still need to loop it following your example.