# LINQ join Table

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
 Dim req_view_item = From ppmp_item In dbcon.tblPPMPs Join ppmp_req In dbcon.tblREQUESTs _
                            On ppmp_item.IDN Equals ppmp_req.IDN
        req_dgv.DataSource = req_view_item
```

What's wrong with my code it didn't join the two table.. this is the result..

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the syntax for an inner join in LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: i didnt get you sir

Comment: i try find some syntax sir

Comment: sir are familiar with stored procedure? past days you gave me your code but i cant make it to stored procedure..  and call the stored procedure using LINQ

Comment: i search it sir ..thanks

Comment: You need to perform SELECT with results of join query and probably using `ToList()` afterwards.