# LINQ Query which is using a query in where clause

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

I want to achieve the below scenario...

Table 1 -  tAccessRequest  of Database 1
columns - RequestId, CardNo and so on......
Table 2  - tBadge of Database 2
Columns  - CardNo, CardStatus and so on...

I created a Request Class as below

```
public class RequestDetails
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }

    public int RequestTypeID { get; set; }

    public string PersonID { get; set; }

    public int SectionCode { get; set; }

    public int RequestStateID { get; set; }

    public int ApprovalStatusID { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am writing two LINQ query

```
List< RequestDetails > listReq = new List< RequestDetails >();

listReq = (from PP in DB1.tAccessRequests
                               where (PP.RequestStateID == 1 || PP.ApprovalStatusID == 1) && PP.SectionCode != null
                               select new RequestDetails
                               {
                                   RequestID = PP.RequestID,
                                   SectionCode = PP.SectionCode.Value 
                               }).ToList();
```

In the second LINQ query I want to achieve

```
var CardNoList = (from BC in prowatchContext.BADGE_C 
                                               where BC.STAT_COD != 'A' && BC.CARDNO in ("Select SectionCodefrom listReq"))
```

How to write the second LINQ query..

Please help

Comment: Check into Linq Inner Join https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the update but as I m hitting two different Databases, the join condition is failing.

Comment: what is your cardNo type ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, sectionCode in RequestDetail class is cardNo

Answer (score 0):

You just use `Contains` for `IN`:

```
var CardNoList = (from BC in prowatchContext.BADGE_C 
                  where BC.STAT_COD != 'A' &&
                        listReq.Select(lr => lr.SectionCode).Contains(BC.CARDNO)
                  ).ToList();
```

Note: If `listReq` is large this may not work unless you do the `Contains` test on the client, in which case you may want to use a `HashSet`:

```
var reqCardNos = new HashSet<int>(listReq.Select(lr => lr.SectionCode));

var CardNoList = prowatchContext.BADGE_C.Where(BC => BC.STAT_COD != 'A')
                                        .AsEnumerable()
                                        .Where(BC => reqCardNos.Contains(BC.CARDNO))
                                        .ToList();
```

The `AsEnumerable` will pull all the matching rows to the client and then filter them, so if `BADGE_C` is very large, this may not work well either, in which case you may have to push `reqCardNos` to the `prowatchContext` database in a temporary table and then do a join.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var CardNoList = from BC in prowatchContext.BADGE_C 
                                              join lr in listReq on BC.CARDNO equals lr.CardNo where BC.STAT_COD != 'A'
                                              select BC
```

Comment: `lr.CardNo` how you get it ?

Comment: I tried this but I m getting the below error ; "Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: var CardNoList = from BC in prowatchContext.BADGE_C 
                                              join lr in listReq on BC.CARDNO equals lr.sectionCode where BC.STAT_COD != 'A'
                                              select BC

Comment: Hi kevin, I tried this but I m getting the above error. The join doesn't work here as we are joining a class object and a entity object

Comment: You may need to convert BC.CARDNO to an int: ..join lr in listReq on int.parse(BC.CARDNO)..