# EF core join using include

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to join related data using `Include` but I am having some difficulties. My models are the following

```
public partial class GBTObject
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public uint OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
    public uint? DeviceId { get; set; }
}

public partial class Device
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public uint OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string UUID { get; set; }
    public bool? Enabled { get; set; }
}

public partial class DeviceState
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public uint OrganizationId { get; set; }

    public uint DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public byte? Event { get; set; }
    public ulong TotalDistance { get; set; }
    public string UserAgent { get; set; }
}

var data = _context.GBTObject
    .Where(x => x.DeviceId != null && x.OrganizationId == _user.OrganizationId)
    .Include(x => x.Device)
    .Include(x => x.State)
```

Then I tried to create a shadow property inside `Device`

`[ForeignKey("Id")]
 public virtual DeviceState State{ get; set; }`

```
var data = _context.GBTObject
    .Where(x => x.DeviceId != null && x.OrganizationId == _user.OrganizationId)
    .Include(x => x.Device)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.State)
```

But it doesn't work cause the it joins using the the `DeviceId` from `GBTObject` with `Id` from `DeviceState`. Changing the foreign key to `DeviceId` results in weird naming errors(it names the `GBTObject.DeviceId` to `GBTObject.DeviceId1` and then it complains that it doesn't exist and looks like a bug).

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: What type of relationship between `Device` and `DeviceState` are you trying to create? With the original models, it would be one-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var data = from gbt in _context.GBTObject
               join ds in _context.DeviceState
               on gbt.DeviceId equals ds.DeviceId
               where gbt.DeviceId != null && gbt.OrganizationId == _user.OrganizationId
               select gbt;
```

Also check this link for further info about joining in `LINQ`:

[What is the syntax for an inner join in LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: `Include` and `ThenIclude` are producing left joins. In this case I need a left join. Also if this work correctly it would help to make this kind of joins more concise and clear.

Comment: `join [...] on` is also left join. See here: http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/linq-left-join-example-in-c.html

Comment: I know that you can use join for left joins but the syntax gets complicated if you join 2,3 tables. As I am rewriting some code I want to avoid this syntax.