# Need help converting SQL into LINQ

Tags: linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

```
SELECT ra.ResidentID, ra.RoomID, r.Number, ra.StartDate, p.FacilityID
FROM( 
    SELECT ResidentID, MAX(StartDate) AS max_start
    FROM RoomAssignments
    GROUP BY ResidentID
    ) m

    INNER JOIN RoomAssignments ra
        ON ra.ResidentID = m.ResidentID
        AND ra.StartDate = m.max_start

    INNER JOIN Rooms r
        ON r.ID = ra.RoomID

    INNER JOIN Person p 
        ON p.ID = ra.ResidentID

    inner join ComplianceStage cs 
        ON cs.Id = p.ComplianceStageID

ORDER BY ra.EndDate DESC
```

I'm trying to figure out how to convert this to C# using LINQ. I'm brand new with C# and LINQ and can't get my subquery to fire correctly. Any chance one of you wizards can turn the lights on for me?

Update-----------------

I think I've got the jist of it, but am having trouble querying for the max startdate:

```
var maxQuery =
        from mra in RoomAssignments
        group mra by mra.ResidentID
        select new { mra.ResidentID, mra.StartDate.Max() };

from ra in RoomAssignments
join r in Rooms on ra.RoomID equals r.ID
join p in Persons on ra.ResidentID equals p.ID
where ra.ResidentID == maxQuery.ResidentID
where ra.StartDate == maxQuery.StartDate

orderby ra.ResidentID, ra.StartDate descending
select new {ra.ResidentID, ra.RoomID, r.Number, ra.StartDate, p.FacilityID}
```

Comment: You might want to read "[*What is the syntax for an inner join in LINQ to SQL?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37324/1364007)"

Comment: That is a very helpful link. Thank you.

Comment: You might find my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) helpful as well.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to compile?

Answer (score 0):

Following my [LINQ to SQL Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786), the conversion is pretty straight forward if you just follow the SQL. The only tricky part is `join`ing the range variable from the subquery for max start date to a new anonymous object from `RoomAssignments` that matches the field names.

```
var maxQuery = from mra in RoomAssignments
               group mra by mra.ResidentID into mrag
               select new { ResidentID = mrag.Key, MaxStart = mrag.Max(mra => mra.StartDate) };

var ans = from m in maxQuery
          join ra in RoomAssignments on m equals new { ra.ResidentID, MaxStart = ra.StartDate }
          join r in Rooms on ra.RoomID equals r.ID
          join p in Persons on ra.ResidentID equals p.ID
          join cs in ComplianceStage on p.ComplianceStageID equals cs.Id
          orderby ra.EndDate descending
          select new {
            ra.ResidentID,
            ra.RoomID,
            r.Number,
            ra.StartDate,
            p.FacilityID
          };
```