# How to translate SQL to LINQ with individual field joins?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL statement, that I want to implement in a .NET website project. I don't understand how to join in a particular field, as the fields aren't available when I just select from the table.

My SQL

> SELECT *
>
> FROM [vResidence] c
>
> JOIN [vJobs] j on c.UID = j.UID

This is the LINQ I have tried, but I am stuck at the 'ON' part:

> results = (from j in vJobs
>
> join cr in vResidence on ??? )

When I try 'j.', the only option I get is 'equals'.

Comment: How are you getting the tables from database?

Comment: If you have mapped the database tables correctly then you should have automatically created classes & the fields will be available - allowing for a very similar join _"j.UID==cr.UID"_ - if the fields aren't available then what are vJobs & vResidence instances of?

Comment: Also see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql/8251984

Comment: I didn't know linq uses 'equals' instead of == .... thanks for the help

Comment: As always: don't use `join`, use navigation properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow as this.connect to tables as `JOIN` use `equals` keyword

```
var result = from r in vResidence
             join j vJobs on r.UID equals  j.UID
             select new {[yourcolnum]};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var result = (from j in vJobs
              join cr in vResidence
              on j.UID equals cr.UID
              select new {
                ...
              }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Linq expression is the following:

```
from t1 in Table1
join t2 in Table2
 on t1.ID equals t2.ID
```

The join clause `on` must be do in order: first the first table, then the second.
The keyword `equals` must be use.

Comment: This is not `Lambda` expression, it is again `Linq`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above `Linq` answers, we can do `JOIN` using [Enumerable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.7.2) extension with `Lambda` expressions. Try something like,

```
        var result = vJobs.Join(vResidence, jb => new { jb.UID }, res => new { res.UID },
                     (jb, res) => new { jb, res })
                     .Select(x => x.jb) //Select the required properties (from both objects) with anonymous object or select left/right object
                     .ToList();
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m6YEAz) with sample data.