# Join multiple tables and single output using Entity Framework mvc5

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I am very new to linq query so I need to join multiple tables and single output using Entity Framework mvc5

Below is my 3 table structures and Table_Application is a main table

1) Table_Application

```
Id   ApplicationName    ServiceId     ProductID

1         Myapp           1               1
```

2) Table_Service

```
ServiceId     SName
  1             S1
```

3) Table_Product

```
ProductID     PName
  1             P1
```

I need linq out result data in linq list base on Table_Application ID

```
ApplicationName   SName   PName
 Myapp             S1      P1
```

my sql query some thing like that

```
select t1.ApplicationName,t2.SName,t3.PName from Table_Application t1,Table_Service t2,Table_Product t3 where t1.ServiceId =t2.ServiceId  and t1.ProductID=t3.ProductID and t1.Id="mysessionid"
```

I tried for single table coming but not able to join Table_Service and Table_Product

```
  var IA = db.Applications
      .Where(x => x.ID == Id)
      .Select(IAview => new IAViewModel 
      {
          ApplicationName = IAview.ApplicationName


      }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi @mahzar, have you tried something? Where are you stuck?

Comment: my table structure some other fields shall i post what i tried? and i explain in simple language. @jeroenh

Comment: Ideally you post the C# code you have tried and explain where you are stuck

Comment: I have edited my question please check and confirm. @jeroenh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the syntax for an inner join in LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: I suggest you look at similar questions that have been posted on stack overflow, as well as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)

Comment: Please update the answer. @jeroenh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the LINQ query syntax - it's similar to SQL so can be easier to understand if you're coming from that sort of background.

There's a tutorial on http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-query-syntax which will give you a basic starting point, then you can just add in joins etc as required.

Note that the following is untested and will give you a list of IAViewModel objects, but I think you would want something similar to the following:

```
var a = (from app in db.Applications
join service in db.Services on app.ServiceId equals service.ServiceId
join product in sb.Products on app.ProductId equals product.ProductId
where app.Id == session_id
select new IAViewModel
{
    ApplicationName = app.ApplicationName,
    ServiceName = service.SName,
    ProductName = product.PName
}).ToList();
```

If you only want a single result out of it, you can leave out the `.ToList()` and instead use something like `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: how to pass session value. @Gareth Lewis

Comment: @mazhar I've updated my answer to include the where clause

Comment: I want to assing this view model please check my question your answer given correct list but want to assign like this   .Select(IAview => new IAViewModel. @Gareth Lewis

Comment: @mazhar I've updated my answer to show how you can select a new IAViewModel from the LINQ query

Answer (score 2):

```
 var T = db.Table_Application.Join(
                    db.Table_Service,
                    TA=> TA.ServiceId,
                    TS => TA.ServiceId,
                    (TA,TS ) => new { TA, TS }
                    ).Join(
                    db.Table_Product,
                    TA2=> TA2.TA.ProductID,
                    TP => TP.ProductID,
                    (TA2, TP) => new { TA2, TP }
                    ).Where(c => c.TA.Id == "mysessionid").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I will check and get backup your answer. @Dilip

Comment: how the name will select t1.ApplicationName,t2.SName,t3.PName. @Dilip

Comment: FirstOrDefault() will select all the columns, or you can use Linq Select to filter columns @mazhar