# Combining two tables and writing a query from them into a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 tables in the database - Customer and Product.
I perform the selection by skipping the first row in the table and then getting the top two rows.
The result I need to get in the List cusPod .

```
List<Customer> customers = db.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY CustomerId OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY").ToList();
List<Product> products = db.Database.SqlQuery<Product>("SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY ProductId OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY").ToList();
            var listSas = from p in products
                          join c in customers on p.ProductId equals c.CustomerId
                          select new { ProductId = p.ProductId, ProductName = p.ProductName, DateStart = p.DateStart, DateEnd = p.DateEnd, DateRegister = p.DateRegister, PriceCustomer = p.PriceCustomer, CheckPay = p.CheckPay, CustomerId = p.CustomerId, FIO = c.FIO, Email = c.Email, PhoneNumber = c.PhoneNumber };
            SidebarController.cusPod = listSas.ToList();
```

how do I do this right?

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Comment: You have the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 0):

From the code it seems that you are using entity framework as your ORM, therefore, you can easily use the `Skip` and `Take` methods of EF that are great features instead of writing hard coded sql. for example:

```
db.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.CustomerId).Skip(1).Take(2);
```

The rest of your logic seems fine.