# Convert SQL query into Linq expression

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

There are tables `Subject`, `Student` and `SubjectEnrolled`

- `Subject` table have two columns `SubjectId` and `SubjectName`
- `SubjectEnrolled` table also have two column `StudentID`(foreign key to `StudentTable`) and `SubjectId`(foreign key to `Subject`)

I want to convert this SQL query

```
SELECT SubjectName
FROM Subject
WHERE SubjectId IN 
(
    SELECT SubjectId
    FROM SubjectEnrolled
    WHERE StudentID=7
)
```

Into a Linq or Lamda expression

```
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    var res = from  r in db.Subjects.....
}
```

Comment: use already inner join for sql not IN.

Comment: Please check for this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the syntax for an inner join in LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - SQL : use [`inner join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15) instead `IN` :

```
SELECT SubjectName FROM Subject sub
INNER JOIN SubjectEnrolled subEn on sub.SubjectId = subEn.SubjectId
WHERE subEn.StudentID = 7
```

2 - Linq Query [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins):

```
var res = (from sub in db.Subjects
          join subEn in db.SubjectEnrolleds on sub.SubjectId equals subEn.SubjectId
          where subEn.StudentID = 7).ToList();
```

I hope you find this helpful.