# How to set inner join in linq query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, join, linq-to-sql

I want to set inner join in linq query

Here is my code,

```
var JoinUsingMS = from emp in _productRepository.Table
   join address in _purchaseReminderRepository.Table
  on new { c1 = emp.VendorId, c2 = emp.Name } equals new { c1 = address.VendorId, c2 = address.Product } into bp_sm
   from c in bp_sm.DefaultIfEmpty()
   where emp.Published == true
   select emp;
```

From this query I am getting left join **(track by doing debug)**. While I think so this query is perfect for inner join **(reference link [As Per This Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql))** still output getting the left join

Answer (score 0):

Below updated query for the inner joins:

```
var JoinUsingMS = from emp in _productRepository.Table
   join address in _purchaseReminderRepository.Table
   on new { c1 = emp.VendorId, c2 = emp.Name } 
   equals new { c1 = address.VendorId, c2 = address.Product }
   where emp.Published == true
   select emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Remove the `DefaultIfEmpty` line. That's what creates the left join clause:

```
var JoinUsingMS = 
    from emp in _productRepository.Table
    join address in _purchaseReminderRepository.Table
      on new { c1 = emp.VendorId, c2 = emp.Name } equals new { c1 = address.VendorId, c2 = address.Product } // into bp_sm
    // from c in bp_sm.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where emp.Published == true
    select emp;
```